# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module

Tags: reactjs, module, native, visual-studio-debugging, usb-debugging

Error: Unable to resolve module `cldr-data/supplemental/currencyData` from `src\services\g11n\models\cldr-utilities.js`: cldr-data/supplemental/currencyData could not be found within the project.

After merging the latest PR I am getting this error though I have cldr-data module in package.json.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-string-parser": "^7.18.10",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.5.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "12.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "1.9.6",
    "@wwdrew/react-native-numeric-textinput": "1.1.0",
    "buffer": "5.4.3",
#     "cldr-data": "36.0.0",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
```

I tried following these steps, but'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

1. If the cldr-data module is not installed, install it by running yarn add cldr-data.
2. If the module is already installed, try clearing the watchman watches by running the command watchman watch-del-all in your project directory.
3. Delete the node_modules directory by running rm -rf node_modules, then run yarn install to reinstall all dependencies.
4. Reset Metro's cache by running yarn start --reset-cache.
5. Remove the cache by running rm -rf /tmp/metro-*.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the Geolocation module was not available. The Geolocation package may need to be installed, so run the command below in your project directory:

java-

npm install @react-native-community/geolocation
After installing the package, you can import it in your HomeScreen.js file:

javascript-

import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
Make sure to also add the necessary permissions for accessing device location in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

php-